# When I get 500 Internal Server Errors for Python scripts, where can I find the log file

Tags: python, 500-error, cgi-bin

Sorry for the newb question, I just got a VPS and I've installed Python and moved my site over. Everything works, but when I try to run scripts (in /cgi-bin/ ) I get 500 Internal Server Error. Where can I locate the error log for this?

My info is:
`Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.0.63 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What distribution? Are you using mod_wsgi (with a framework like django?) or running python scripts as a CGI, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/httpd/logs/`

Answer (score 0):

1. Check interpreter is addedd to script, add either `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Check logs at `/var/log/apache2` for detailed errors, if any.
   i found missing pip packages in the log.

   ubuntu@ip:/var/log/apache2$ ll
   total 36
   drwxr-x---  2 root adm     4096 Nov  6 18:08 ./
   drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog  4096 Nov  6 18:57 ../
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm     9543 Nov  6 21:36 access.log
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm    15941 Nov  6 21:35 error.log
   -rw-r-----  1 root adm        0 Nov  6 18:08 other_vhosts_access.log
   ubuntu@ip:/var/log/apache2$

Access the script, example `tail -f http://<ip>/cgi-bin/test-db.py`

```
[Sun Nov 06 21:35:18.928560 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 139738648380992] [client 49.207.201.90:5556] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test-db.py
[Sun Nov 06 21:35:18.928839 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 139738648380992] [client 49.207.201.90:5556] AH01215:   File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/test-db.py", line 3, in <module>: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test-db.py
[Sun Nov 06 21:35:18.929051 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 139738648380992] [client 49.207.201.90:5556] AH01215:     import pymysql: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test-db.py
[Sun Nov 06 21:35:18.929213 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 139738648380992] [client 49.207.201.90:5556] AH01215: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql': /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test-db.py
[Sun Nov 06 21:35:18.941377 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 8303:tid 139738648380992] [client 49.207.201.90:5556] End of script output before headers: test-db.py
```